# Remove element in a list inside a dictionary with python

Tags: python, json, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this `json` structure:

```
{
  "http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Virginia_Potts_(Earth-33900)": [
    "/wiki/Virginia_Potts_(Earth-616)",
    "/wiki/Earth-33900",
    "/wiki/Stark_Industries_(Earth-33900)",
    "/wiki/AAFES_Vol_1_15",
    "/wiki/Washington_State",
    "/wiki/Pepper_Potts",
    "/wiki/Tom_Grummett",
    "/wiki/William_Harms",
    "/wiki/Virginia_Potts_(Earth-616)#Abilities",
    "/wiki/Seattle"
  ],
  "http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Virginia_Potts_(Earth-5631)": [
    "/wiki/Pepper_Potts",
    "/wiki/Earth-5631",
    "/wiki/Iron_Man_and_Power_Pack_Vol_1_1",
    "/wiki/Marc_Sumerak"
  ],
...
```

I want to iterate over the json and for each item verify if one of its links (it's a list of links) is not contained in another json with a complete list of characters (in the following code it's `characters`). 
In this case I want to eliminate the link from the list. At the end save the dictionary (`links_ref`) in a file.

```
for item in links_ref:
        for link in links_ref[item]:
            if link not in characters:
                links_ref[item].pop(link)
json.dump(links_ref, open('links_raf.json', 'w'))
```

This code of course doesn't work, I tried also with `del link` but, even if it didn't launch an exception, it didn't remove the link from the list too.

Hope someone can help me, I'm new to python so I'll be more than happy if you can suggest a better solution to my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify the list while you are iterating over it. You can make use of list comprehensions though in order to filter out the links:

```
for item, links in links_ref.items():
    links_ref[item] = [link for link in links if link in characters]
```

Comment: Wasn't exactly my solution but it helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Immutable way:

```
filtered_links_ref = {i: [l for l in links_ref[i] if l not in characters] for i in links_ref}
```

Or try to use `set`s:

```
character_set = frozenset(characters)
filtered_links_ref = {i: frozenset(links_ref[i]) - character_set for i in links_ref}
```